# the windows phone emulator wasn't able to create the virtual machine

Tags: windows-phone, hyper-v, ipv4, windows-phone-8-emulator

I just installed it on my windows 8. It's NOT running on a VM but is running at a macbook with bootcamp.
When I try to emulate my app, I get this first error:

[image]

But then I click "Retry" and give the permission, so it runs normally.

But then, when the windows phone window appears, I get a "loading" screen and then this error appears:

[image]

Just for better tagging the post I will write the error: "something happened while creating a switch: Xde couldn't find an IPv4 adress for the host machine"

Answer (score 1):

You must enable virtualization in BIOS and go to Control Panel->Programs->Turn Windows features on or off and choose Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

1- Open the Control Panel.

2- Then programs.

3- Turn Windows features on or off.

4- Further selection for hyper-v.

5- Restart the computer.

6- Repeat the previous steps but put the selection on hyper-v.

7- Restart the computer.

Enjoy ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got to the solution, but I just had the same situation. It turns out that older VPN clients may have compatibility problems with Windows 8. I solved the issue by uninstalling VPN client (and also making sure Hyper-V was enabled).